# Round negative values to zero in influx query?

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to set a lower bounds of zero on my influx query result so that negative values are replaced with zero in the result. e.g. For the query:

```
SELECT x from measurement
```

If my raw response is

```
time                x
----                -
1632972969471900180 0
1632972969471988621 -130
1632972969472238055 803
```

then i want to alter the query so that the result is:

```
time                x'
----                -
1632972969471900180 0
1632972969471988621 0
1632972969472238055 803
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to use the `ABS` absolute value function, adding the absolute value to the original value and dividing by 2. This maps negative values to zero and leaves posiive (and zero) values unchanged. e.g.

```
SELECT (x + ABS(x)) / 2 from measurement
```

```
time                x                        x'
----                -                        -
1632972969471900180 0     = 0 + 0 / 2      = 0
1632972969471988621 -130  = -130 + 130 / 2 = 0
1632972969472238055 803   = 803 + 803 / 2  = 803
```